# Get attributes value from items in order

Tags: attributes, orders

I'm actually working on a website in Magento 2.

I have to print entire order in PDF.

But I don't know how can I get the products attribute value.

There is my code :

```
 foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

                $product = $item->getProduct();
                $itemName = $item->getName();
                $itemAdr = $product->getAdressage();
                $itemQty = (int)($item->getData('qty_ordered'));
                $itemEan = $item->getProduct()->getData('ean_code');
                $sku = $item->getProductId();

                $page->drawText($itemQty,20,$y, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText($itemAdr,45, $y, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText($itemName, 100, $y, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText($itemEan, 500,$y, 'UTF-8');
                $page->drawText($sku, 550,$y,'UTF-8');
                $y = $y - 20;
            }
```

I can only get itemName and Quantity Ordered...

Can you help me on this feature ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get product attributes, you need to create product collection factory, pass product_id in it and call function to get attribute value. See below code to get guidance.
Inside your class add product model factory:

```
protected $product;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->product = $product; 
    }
```

and inside your foreach loop:

```
  $_product = $this->product->create()->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
 // suppose product has "no_shipping_method" attribute, you can get it's value by calling function like getNoShippingMethod() as shown below
            if ($_product->getNoShippingMethod()) {
                //your code in true case;
}
```